# How to remove an array from a resultset from fetchall

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result from a mysql query and need to reduce the result by 1 or more arrays based on a condition. Here is what I tried.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

It will create a resultset of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [colour] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [colour] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

How can I remove the whole array with the name watermelon so it $result contains only the pear element?

Here is what I tried, but it did not work:

```
foreach ($result AS $items=>$vals){
    foreach ($items AS $item=>$value){
    if ($item =="name" AND $value=='watermelon'){
        unset($result[$items]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Jack

Comment: Filtering the underlying dataset in sql to exclude certain records?

Comment: Why cant you filter the required results from the db itself. Something like `SELECT name, colour FROM fruit WHERE name = 'watermelon'`

Comment: I think the above meant to say `SELECT name, colour FROM fruit WHERE name <> 'watermelon'`. But yes it's far from obvious why you don't just use SQL to filter the data - much more efficient

Comment: That is exactly what came to my mind after posting this. Just adapt the WHERE clause in the query. Ummmgh. Sometimes I think to complicated. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreach` statements & their variables aren't being referenced properly.  It goes `key`=>`value`

```php
foreach ($result AS $index=>$item){
    if($item['name'] === 'watermelon')
        unset($result[$index]);
    }
}
```

But like others have commented, the best way to do this is just throw a `WHERE` condition on your query & let the DB do the filtering.

Comment: Thank you "Quasipickle", I realized it myself! In Germany we say "Brett vorm Kopf" :-)